# ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY in Java

Tags: java

```
 try {

        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/employee", "root", "root");
        String query = "select * from sample;";
        Statement stmt = con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
        stmt.executeQuery(query);
        ResultSet rs = stmt.getResultSet();
        rs.absolute(3);

        while (rs.next()) {
            System.out.println(rs.getString("name"));
        }
            rs.beforeFirst();
            while (rs.next()) {
            System.out.println(rs.getString("name"));
        }

 while (rs.previous()) {
            System.out.println(rs.getString("name"));
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

This is working fine.
Here `ResultSet` is `TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY` but i can go in previous direction also. 
Can anyone explain me that, i googled it but could not get any satisfactory answers.

Comment: Please refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23817619/mysql-resultset-scrollable-updatable-not-working-as-expected. Actually, the mysql driver caches the result and makes it scrollable. To avoid this we need to create a resultset with explicitly mentioning `TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY` and `stmt.setFetchSize(Integer.MIN_VALUE);`

Answer (score 2):

As [stated on **roseindia.net**](http://www.roseindia.net/tutorial/java/jdbc/jdbcresultset/jdbcresultsetafterlast.html):

> This `ResultSet` method set cursor to after last record. It sets the
>   cursor position to last + 1. The `void afterLast()` moves the cursor
>   to the end of this `ResultSet` object, just after the last row. This
>   method has no effect if the result set contains no rows.
>
> Syntax:
>
> ```
> ResultSet rs;
>
> void rs.afterLast();
> ```
>
> Now we will create example using this method. In this example, the
>   afterLast() point the last position in the resultset object and the
>   resultset previous() moves the cursor to the previous row in this
>   ResultSet object.

Comment: Then why we say that we cannot scroll in a Resultset with type 'TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY', i have tried setting the position using 'absolute(5)' and then 'absolute(1)', then iterate it again and it worked