# MySQL ResultSet scrollable/updatable not working as expected

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, scroll, resultset

I have a test JDBC program that tries to alter the Scrollability and Updatability features of a ResultSet. Unfortunately, all the combinations of `TYPE_` and `CONCUR_` seem to produce the same result (`TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE` and `CONCUR_READ_ONLY`).

Even with the default (`TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY`) it's possible to scroll through the ResultSet. Can anyone explain why this is?

I am using MySQL 5.6 and JDK7. Here is the code:

```
public class ResultSetTest3 {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Connection conn;

        try {
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/bd", "user", "password");

            Statement sta = conn.createStatement();
            sta.execute("DELETE FROM test");
            sta.close();

            PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO test VALUES(?, ?)");
            for(int i=1; i<=100; i++)
            {
                ps.setInt(1, i);
                ps.setString(2, "Teste " + i);
                ps.addBatch();
            }
            ps.executeBatch();
            ps.close();

            System.out.println("TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY  CONCUR_READ_ONLY");
            result(conn, ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
            System.out.println("===================================");

            System.out.println("TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE  CONCUR_READ_ONLY");
            result(conn, ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
            System.out.println("===================================");

            System.out.println("TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE  CONCUR_READ_ONLY");
            result(conn, ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
            System.out.println("===================================");

            System.out.println("TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY  CONCUR_UPDATABLE");
            result(conn, ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
            System.out.println("===================================");

            System.out.println("TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE  CONCUR_UPDATABLE");
            result(conn, ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
            System.out.println("===================================");

            System.out.println("TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE  CONCUR_UPDATABLE");
            result(conn, ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
            System.out.println("===================================");

            conn.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static void result(Connection conn, int type, int update) throws SQLException
    {
        Statement sta = conn.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
        ResultSet rs = sta.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM test");

        System.out.println(rs.getConcurrency() + " " + update);
        System.out.println(rs.getType() + " " + type);

        try
        {
            rs.absolute(10);
            System.out.println(rs.getInt(1) + " - " + rs.getString(2));

            rs.relative(20);
            System.out.println(rs.getInt(1) + " - " + rs.getString(2));

            rs.previous();
            System.out.println(rs.getInt(1) + " - " + rs.getString(2));

            rs.first();
            System.out.println(rs.getInt(1) + " - " + rs.getString(2));

            try {
                System.out.println("AGORA!!!");
                Thread.sleep(20000);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e);
            }
            rs.absolute(3);
            System.out.println(rs.getInt(1) + " - " + rs.getString(2));
        }
        catch(SQLException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Not Scrollable");
        }

        try
        {
            rs.next();
            rs.next();
            rs.next();
            rs.next();

            rs.deleteRow();

            rs.next();
            rs.updateString(2, "TesteUpdate");

            rs.insertRow();
        }
        catch(SQLException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Not Updatable");
        }

        rs.close();
        sta.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your `result`-method isn't using the `type` and `update` parameters, you always use `createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY)`

Comment: Also note that JDBC disallows scrolling on a `FORWARD_ONLY` resultset, but maybe MySQL upgrades to a scrollable result set as it is cached anyway by default.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel re: "maybe MySQL upgrades to a scrollable result set" - That appears to be the case. `rs.last()` and `rs.previous()` seem to work fine on a MySQL ResultSet even when I explicitly specify `ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY`. Thanks for mentioning it.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel: Actually I changed the code for debug and then I forgot to post the original code which I use createStatement(type, update), but the result was the same.

Comment: @GordThompson: The problem was the caching. Using the fetchSize method worked. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Mark Rotteveel mentions in a comment to the question, MySQL caches ResultSet data by default (also discussed in a blog article by 
Ben J. Christensen [here](http://benjchristensen.com/2008/05/27/mysql-jdbc-memory-usage-on-large-resultset/)). An apparent side-effect of this caching is that MySQL Connector/J will "upgrade" a TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY ResultSet to actually be scrollable:

```java
Statement s = dbConnection.createStatement(
        ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY, 
        ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM testdata");
rs.last();
System.out.println(String.format("Current row number: %d", rs.getRow()));
rs.previous();
System.out.println(String.format("Current row number: %d", rs.getRow()));
```

displays

```
Current row number: 3
Current row number: 2
```

According to the blog article cited above, the way to prevent caching and "stream" the ResultSet data is to use `Statement.setFetchSize`:

```java
Statement s = dbConnection.createStatement(
        ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY, 
        ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
s.setFetchSize(Integer.MIN_VALUE);
ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM testdata");
rs.next();
System.out.println("Data from first row: " + rs.getString(2));
System.out.println("now let's try rs.last() ...");
try {
    rs.last();
    System.out.println("... Okay, done.");
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("... Exception: " + e.getMessage());
}
```

resulting in

```
Data from first row: Gord
now let's try rs.last() ...
... Exception: Operation not supported for streaming result sets
```

Comment: +1 for a thorough answer, I didn't have time to investigate ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try in this way to create a *Scroll-Insensitive*, *read only* ResultSet object statement object.

```
Statement sta = conn.createStatement(
          ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,
          ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
```

instead of

```
Statement sta = conn.createStatement();
```

Do the same for `PreparedStatement` as well.

---

> Through this `ResultSet` type the cursor can move in any direction. It is insensitive which means result set that does not reflect changes made while it is still open. It is default resultset type for MySql.

**Must read** [Retrieving and Modifying Values from Result Sets](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/retrieving.html)

Comment: That is the statement used for insert, where scrollability is irrelevant. The problem is simply that he always creates a `FORWARD_ONLY` in the method `result`.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel may be OP is using it in `result()` method.