# Result Set not updateable when I use updateable field

Tags: java, sql, prepared-statement, resultset, updatable-views

I am running this code but I don't know what is wrong in this code.

I define the statement with field SENSITIVE & UPDATABLE but when I run the code this error message appears in the console:

> Result Set not updatable.This result set must come from a statement
> that was created with a result set type of ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE,
> the query must select only one table, and must select all primary keys
> from that table.
>
> See the JDBC 2.1 API Specification,  section 5.6 for
> more details.
>
> Process finished with exit code 0

Please guide me. Here is the code:

```
import java.sql.*;


public class Main
{

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Connection con=getConnection();

    try
    {
        String query="Select title from movie1";
        Statement stmt=con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
        ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery(query);
        rs.absolute(13);
        rs.deleteRow();

    }
    catch (SQLException e)
    {
       System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }

}

private static Connection getConnection()
{
    Connection con=null;
    try
    {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        String url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/Movies";
        String user="user4545";
        String pw="j4545j";
        con= DriverManager.getConnection(url,user,pw);
    }
    catch (ClassNotFoundException e)
    {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        System.exit(0);
    }
    catch (SQLException e)
    {
        System.out.println("SQL Exeption happend.");
        System.exit(0);
    }
    return con;
}
}
```

Comment: i use intelliJ IDEA

Comment: which command exactly is producing this error?

Comment: rs.deleteRow();

Comment: You want to try with `TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE`

Comment: I try that and Replace TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE with  TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE  but that error again appear.

Comment: Related, but not an exact duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23817619/mysql-resultset-scrollable-updatable-not-working-as-expected The solution to explicitly set a fetch size might work for this problem as well.